# dataannotations que permita solo numeros

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Compañeros

Actualmente estoy manejando asp.net mvc con entityframework y estoy realizando un formulario para agregar registros

Estoy limitando lo que el usuario escribe con dataannotations de los cuales me funcionan bien pero aun no encuentro la forma de un dataannotations que me regule que el usuario solo le permita escribir en textbox números hasta 12 dígitos y si escribe letras no se lo permita o le genere error

quedaría agradecido si me pueden ayudar con esto

Comment: Podrías detallar un poco más? Sería bueno que pongas parte de tu controller, modelo y viewmodel, también de la vista.

Answer (score 2):

En el viewmodel (para la validación del lado del servidor):

```
[RegularExpression("(^[0-9]+$)", ErrorMessage = "Solo se permiten números")]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "El número es obligatorio")]
[StringLength(12, ErrorMessage = "El número es demasiado largo")]
public string Numero { get; set; }
```

Y si quieres, puedes obligarle a que ingrese solo números del lado del cliente de esta forma:

```
<input asp-for="Numero" type="tel" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')">
```

Pero siempre debes validar del lado del servidor, ya que cualquiera podría modificar el código HTML de tu página

Answer (score 0):

Intenta añadiendo esto en tu vista.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Instruccion, new {**@maxlength="50"**, @class = "form-control"})
```

Con esto limitas a solo introducir 50 caracteres.